# Remove the round brackets and keep the text?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, grep

I have more than 1000 titles with round brackets. All have a paragraph style. I'm trying to keep the title\text but removing the brackets. I managed to find them in the GREP, but I could not find what should I write in CHANGE area to keep the text without the brackets.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use GREP here.. Just run the command twice... find `(` then find `)`. Running the find twice will take less time than it did to post your question.

... leave the `Change to:` field **blank** and click `Change` or `Change All`.

---

Unless, of course, there are parenthesis elsewhere in the copy you *do* want to retain. You could then target via character/paragraph styles, if possible, or adjust the GREP. The GREP in the question is selecting the brackets **and** everything between them. I'm not versed enough in GREP to explain how to exclude the contents *between* the brackets.